# C program: how do I read this recursive program

Tags: c

this the code and i confused to read this program can anybody tell me how this program running.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int box(int a, int b){
    if(a>b)
    {
        return 1 +box(a-1, b);
    }
    else if(a<b)
    {
        return 1 + box(a,b-1);
    }
    else
    {
        return a+b;
    }
}
int main(){

    printf("%d", box(12,17));
    return 0;
}
```

it's calling else if? but the final output is 29, it's calling else?. im confusing

Comment: The `box()` function will return the sum of a and b. If a != b, the function will recurse |a-b| times. Adding one to the final sum on each iteration to make up for the decrement, which eventually establishes equality and terminates recursion (a==b)

Answer (score 1):

We can add some `printf` calls to see what is happening:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int box(int a, int b, int depth) {
    ++depth;
    if (a > b) {
        printf("%s: depth = %d, %d > %d\n", __func__, depth, a, b);
        printf("    return 1 + %s(%d - 1, %d)\n", __func__, a, b);
        return 1 + box(a - 1, b, depth);
    }
    else if (a < b) {
        printf("%s: depth = %d, %d < %d\n", __func__, depth, a, b);
        printf("    return 1 + %s(%d, %d - 1)\n", __func__, a, b);
        return 1 + box(a, b - 1, depth);
    }
    else {
        printf("%s: depth = %d, %d = %d\n", __func__, depth, a, b);
        printf("    return %d + %d\n", a, b);
        return a + b;
    }
}
int main(){
    int depth = 0;
    printf("%d\n", box(12, 17, depth));
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
box: depth = 1, 12 < 17
    return 1 + box(12, 17 - 1)
box: depth = 2, 12 < 16
    return 1 + box(12, 16 - 1)
box: depth = 3, 12 < 15
    return 1 + box(12, 15 - 1)
box: depth = 4, 12 < 14
    return 1 + box(12, 14 - 1)
box: depth = 5, 12 < 13
    return 1 + box(12, 13 - 1)
box: depth = 6, 12 = 12
    return 12 + 12
29
```

**Explanation**

The program follows the `a < b` path until `a = 12` and `b = 12`. Then it returns `12 + 12`. The final value is

```
24 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 29
```

**Note**

I modified `box` to accept a `depth` parameter. Using a `static` variable might have resulted in a `depth` value that was incorrect.

Comment: Why did you declare `depth` static?

Comment: thank you very much for the explaination :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a recursive function.

Mind first the "stop condition" of the recusivity. Here it is **a == b** (the last else) and so the function return **a + b**.

Second thing keep in mind the call stack and values of a and b are proper at each call level.

If a < b  the function return 1 + box(a,b-1). the b-1 takes place of b in the call level. The recusion contenu until a == b

Exemple : box(2,4)

box(2,4) == 1 + box(2,3) == 1 + (1 + box(2+2)) == (1+(1+(2+2)))

Comment: thank you very much for the explaination :)

Answer (score 0):

A other answers point out a way into such code is to look at the base case.
That's the case that doesn't make a recursive call (a call to `box` in a call to `box`).
There has to be one or all calls will call `box` and you'll get the error this site is named for - Stack Overflow!

So by looking at the if-else chain we see that if a>b it calls recursively. If a<b it calls recursively. It only doesn't call recursively if a==b.

So if a==b the function returns the sum a+b.

Now the other two cases amount to 'if a and b are different reduce the greater by 1 and return 1+ box for those values.

So try the minimal case. If a=b+1 it returns 1+box(a-1,b) and that's 1+box(b,b).

But hang on 1+box(b,b) == 1+b+b == a+b (because a=b+1)

If a=b+2 it returns 1+box(b+1,b) == 1+1+box(b,b)=2+b+b == a+b again!

By induction(*) we see that if a=b+n (n>=0) we return n+box(b,b)=n+b+b.
OK, proper hang on. a=b+n so that's a+b always.

So if a > b we return n+b+b. But that's just a+b.
By a similar argument if b>a we do the same.

The function is a round about way of calculating a+b by reducing the larger variable by one and (in effect) totting up how many reductions we made to get to the lesser.

A top-tip is when faced with a recursion function study it (and test) it with some base cases (here a==b) and then work through some cases that recurse once, then twice and so on until the the pattern becomes clear.

In my experience when you study or build recursive functions you should:

1. Test the base cases. No recursion/
2. Test the cases that recurse once.
3. Then test cases that recurse twice.
4. Then start testing cases that recurse some times (4,5) a few more (8,15).
5. Finally test some monsters that recurse dozens of times.

You can increase the recursive depth your testing exponentially roughly doubling each time and within a handful of tests you're done.

(*) To determine what recursive functions do often requires an understanding of 'induction' because recursive functions are in essence a recurrence relationship.
If your mathematical background doesn't include reduction, I recommend a quick primer.

Yeah, I know they told you that Computer Science doesn't require you to be any good at maths. They lied a bit. You're going to need some!

Here's a toy unit test that confirms box(a,b)=a+b.

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int box(int a, int b){
    if(a>b)
    {
        return 1 +box(a-1, b);
    }
    else if(a<b)
    {
        return 1 + box(a,b-1);
    }
    else
    {
        return a+b;
    }
}

int test(int a,int b){
    int sum=a+b;
    int rf=box(a,b);
    if(rf!=sum){
        printf("box(%d,%d)==%d!=%d\n",a,b,rf,sum);
        return 1;   
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    int errors=0;
    errors+=test(1,1);
    errors+=test(2,2);
    errors+=test(3,5);
    errors+=test(5,3);
    errors+=test(53,99);
    errors+=test(45565,3);
    errors+=test(2,8476);
    errors+=test(44568,8733);
    errors+=test(2,-8476);
    errors+=test(-42568,8733);
    errors+=test(-42568,-8733);
    
    if(errors==0){
        printf("SUCCESS! box(a,b)==a+b\n"); 
    }else{
        printf("FAILED!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for the explaination :)

Answer (score 0):

**First the main executes**

```
int main(){
    printf("%d\n", **box(12, 17)**); //this functions calls
    return 0;
}
```

**First Iteration**
*as we know a=12 and b=17*

```
int box(int a, int b){
    if(a>b) 
    {
        return 1 +box(a-1, b);
    }
    else if(a<b) **// this will be execute**
    {
        return 1 + box(a,b-1); //now b=16 and return has 1
    }
    else
    {
        return a+b;
    }
}
```

**Next Iteration**
*as we know a=12 and b=16 *

```
int box(int a, int b){
    if(a>b) 
    {
        return 1 +box(a-1, b);
    }
    else if(a<b) **// this will be execute**
    {
        return 1 + box(a,b-1); //now b=15 and return has 1+1
    }
    else
    {
        return a+b;
    }
}
```

**Next Iteration**
*as we know a=12 and b=15 *

```
int box(int a, int b){
    if(a>b) 
    {
        return 1 +box(a-1, b);
    }
    else if(a<b) **// this will be execute**
    {
        return 1 + box(a,b-1); //now b=14 and return has 1+1+1
    }
    else
    {
        return a+b;
    }
}
```

**Next Iteration**
*as we know a=12 and b=14 *

```
int box(int a, int b){
    if(a>b) 
    {
        return 1 +box(a-1, b);
    }
    else if(a<b) **// this will be execute**
    {
        return 1 + box(a,b-1); //now b=13 and return has 1+1+1+1
    }
    else
    {
        return a+b;
    }
}
```

**Next Iteration**
*as we know a=12 and b=13 *

```
int box(int a, int b){
    if(a>b) 
    {
        return 1 +box(a-1, b);
    }
    else if(a<b) **// this will be execute**
    {
        return 1 + box(a,b-1); //now b=12 and return has 1+1+1+1+1
    }
    else
    {
        return a+b;
    }
}
```

**Next Iteration**
*as we know a=12 and b=12 *

```
int box(int a, int b){
    if(a>b) 
    {
        return 1 +box(a-1, b);
    }
    else if(a<b) **// this will be execute**
    {
        return 1 + box(a,b-1); 
    }
    else
    {
        return a+b; *//as we know a=12 and b=12  and return has 1+1+1+1+1 so total is 28*
    }
}
```

> IF still confused, you can ask.. Don't forget to like the answer:p

Comment: thank you very much for the explaination :)